# What is the behavior of mv on /?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, mv

One of our users accidentally performed `mv /* ../` without root permission. After checking the effects using `diff` I was surprised to find that `mv` apparently functioned as `cp` when applied to the `/` dir.

So my questions are:

1. Is this standard behavior for the `mv` command?
2. Is there anything else I should check to make sure no damage was done to the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the target (`../`) was somewhere inside `/home/` or another mountpoint where the filesystem other than `/` was mounted.

> 1. Is this standard behavior for the `mv` command?

Yes. If a file is moved between filesystems, it's copied, then the source is deleted and the copy ownership is adjusted to mirror the source. I guess this was the case but the "delete" part threw "permission denied" errors and nothing was deleted (or almost nothing, I'll get back to it in a while).

If the moving should happen within a single filesystem, `mv` would try to update directory entries without copying. When a regular user tries to move something somewhere within the root filesystem, the process usually hits "permission denied" and nothing at all happens. But in this case the target filesystem was different, as described above. Yet `mv` at some point tried to move the `/home/` (or other) mountpoint within *its* filesystem, deeper into the tree where `../` was. This action is obviously impossible, you cannot move directory into its subdirectory. This way the user's files on the same filesystem as `../` were left intact, despite the fact he or she could move them to `../` one by one.

The only **danger I can think of** is the following scenario: if the user could delete any files and/or directories on a filesystem *other* than where the `../` was, `mv` would act like `cp` and then the source files and/or directories *would be deleted*. You should check if it could happen and how severe it was. In this case some files may have to be moved back. This shouldn't happen if the user is an entirely regular user. The user may have moved some files away from `/tmp/` but it's probably nothing serious.

> 2. Is there anything else I should check to make sure no damage was done to the system?

I don't think so. If the system is properly configured, a regular user can do nothing to harm it. Well, in this case the target filesystem may be full due to those unexpectedly copied files but that's it. After you deal with the dangerous scenario described above, remove the copy and your system *should* be fine.

I would do all the cleaning as *the* user, not root, even if somebody else has to do it (like `sudo -u user rm something`). The point is to avoid the system damage in case of another mistake.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the thorough answer.